# a question about definition of graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

the definition of graph says "a graph is an ordered pair G=(V,E) comprising a set V of vertices together with a set E of edges." My question is  can the set V and E be infinite? If yes then i need an example of that type of graph. If not ,then why? I am new to graph theory.

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Both can be infinite, or either one can be infinite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since neither answer so far has provided the example you were looking for: An example is afforded by the graph whose vertices are the natural numbers, with an edge between $j$ and $k$ if $j\mid k$.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, we add the restriction and demand that $V$ is finite. To ask "why" does not entirely make sense in the context of mathematics, just like it does not make sense to ask "why does the triangle inequality hold in metric spaces?"

We work with finite sets $V$ because that's what is interesting, and also because that allows us to create mathematical structures that can be used to model the real world.

Of course, infinite graphs could also be used to model the real world, but finite graphs are easier to handle (we can prove more theorems about them) and usually sufficient. The cost we pay to move to infinite graphs outweighs the benefits of a more general theory.